# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

poem = '''\
Программировать весело.
Если работа скучна,
Чтобы придать ей веселый тон-
используй Python!
'''

```
f = open('poem.pxp', 'w')
f.write(poem)
f.close()
```

f = open('poem.txt', 'r')

```
while True:
    line = f.readline
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
```

print(line, end='')
f.close()

Comment: `Python` не может найти файл `poem.txt`. Вы уверены, что он существует?

Comment: Тоесть мне нужно создать его за программой?

Comment: У Вас есть инструкция `open('poem.txt', 'r')`, которая должна открыть на чтение файл. Но файла нет. Конечно, перед этим его нужно создать, причём неважно как, можно и средствами `Python`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное))

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в коде есть следующая инструкция:

```py
open('poem.txt', 'r')
```

Она должна открыть на чтение файл `poem.txt`.
В результате её исполнения возникает следующая ошибка:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'poem.txt'
```

В переводе она означает:

> Нет такого файла или каталога: 'poem.txt'

Чтобы решить проблему, необходимо создать файл до момента его открытия.